Idiomatic way to query DB data server side and use result client side with SvelteKit
Currently I am working on a SvelteKit app that accepts file uploads.
On the upload page I have a dropdown to select a client and one to select a client location. Each client can have multiple locations.
I only want to show the user locations for the selected client. I do not want to query all locations and then do the filtering in the browser, as the total number of all locations could be very large.
My first idea was SvelteKit data loading, but as far as I know a server side load function cannot access client state. Therefore I wouldn't be able to filter client locations based on the selected client.
A different way to implement this would be an API route that queries the client locations for a specific client. That doesn't feel very idiomatic to me though.
Is there something I am missing or a better way to implement this in general?

Don't know if it's optimal, but here comes a suggestion.
Split the process into two parts. First have a small form where the user can select the client, and after that the user comes to the second form, where she can select the rest. You can for example use the URL /upload for the first form, and the URL /upload/CLIENT_ID for the second form, or /upload?clientId=CLIENT_ID.
The described way makes it easy to work for clients that have client-side JS disabled. You can achieve the same thing using a single form on the same page, but then you need to write much more logic to handle both the cases client-side JS disabled and client-side JS enabled respectively.
